# Wamp redirecting to ISP search page instead of mysite.dev after using Safe Search Replace tool

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

I have installed a Wordpress site on mysite.dev using WAMP and everything works fine and it installs fine, so I know it works.  I then delete and do a fresh install, copying my live site files and database to my localhost www directory.

After exporting the live database and importing it into local, I use http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to replace all the links to mysite.dev

After this has completed successfully I go to mysite.dev and oddly it redirects me to my ISPs search page which is http://www.dnsrsearch.com

My htaccess has the standard WP jargon

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is happening, it's weird to me and I've tried a lot of common fixes already, including resetting port 80.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  I have struggled with it for a couple hours now, so it's time to ask you fine folks.

Comment: Do you have `mysite.dev` in your hosts file?

Comment: Yes I do and i have the vhost setup in my htdocs.  Also the fresh Wordpress install on the same vhost worked fine, so that's not the issue.

Comment: What address was it looking for when you got sent to the ISP search page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wamp and IIS are fighting over port 80. IIS will always win that battle. You can go to Services and disable it. Or follow the directions below.

---

Click on the orange WAMP Icon > **Apache** > **Http config**

---

Find:

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

---

Change to:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080
```

---

then go to: localhost:8080/YourSiteFolder

---

Also check to make sure that: **rewrite_module** is checked.

Orange WAMP Icon > Apache > Services > **rewrite_module**

Comment: I've done all that and my icon is green.  rewrite is on and IIS is off.  I don't think it has anything to do with my wamp install since a fresh install of Wordpress worked just fine, it's only when I migrated my live database that the issues arose... than again I could be wrong.  I can navigate to my home page using localhost port 80 but not any other pages.

Comment: Did you set Debug to true in wp-config? It should give you some more error messages... might be a good place to start?